# Using a string as IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, string, windows-8, windows-store-apps

In .NET for Windows Store Apps –it seems– you cannot use strings as Enumerables anymore. The following code works for desktop applications, but not for apps:

```
public static bool SolelyConsistsOfLetters(string s)
{
    return s.All(c => char.IsLetter(c));
}
```

The error is

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'All' and no extension method 'All' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But I'm not missing an assembly reference or `using System.Linq;`. The following code **does** work:

```
public static IEnumerable<char> StringAsEnumerable(string s)
{
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        yield return c;
    }
}

public static bool SolelyConsistsOfLetters(string s)
{
    return StringAsEnumerable(s).All(c => char.IsLetter(c));
}
```

The problem is, `s as IEnumerable<char>` does not work (error: "Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' (..)") and `s.GetEnumerator()` is not available.

My questions:

1. Is there really no elegant way to use strings as Enumerables (without a helper method as above)? I feel like I must be missing something totally obvious.
2. Since the string does not behave like an Enumerable, why/how does foreach work here?

Comment: “`s as IEnumerable<char>` does not work” What *does* it do?

Comment: @svick: question updated

Comment: it's odd that `GetEnumerator` doesn't exist, because to my knowledge, that is what `foreach` uses to iterate an object.

Comment: [`String.GetEnumerator` isn't supported by .NET for Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.getenumerator.aspx) (compare to the same page for [`String.GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode.aspx)). I'd imagine the `foreach` is being optimised into a `for` loop by the compiler.

Comment: @Default: That's what confuses me, too

Comment: @Rawling Yeah, but that should be just an optimization, it shouldn't compile without `GetEnumerator()`. Also, it seems [the non-generic `GetEnumerator()` is supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344612.aspx). @Sebastian Does `s.Cast<char>().All(…)` work?

Comment: @svick That'd explain it, then - I think `foreach` _uses_ the non-generic one, and I bet `Cast` works then.

Comment: I would consider this a bug, so [I reported it](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/777868/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [`String.IEnumerable<Char>.GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc672334.aspx) method is not supported in .NET for Windows Store applications, however, the non generic [`String.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344612.aspx) is supported so that's why the `foreach` approach works.

Based on that I believe it should also be possible to do:

```
s.Cast<char>().All(c => char.IsLetter(c))
```

---

**UPDATE** (regarding Jani comment)
The `foreach` is already performing the cast by defining the each variable as `char`. The nongeneric `IEnumerable` version returns object and at compile time every cast from object to any other type is acceptable so that's why it works.

The following code will also compile fine but will fail at runtime:

```
var valid = new object[] {'1', '2', '3'};

foreach (char c in valid)
    Console.WriteLine(c);

var invalid = new object[] { 1, 2, 3 };

foreach (char c in invalid)
    Console.WriteLine(c); // Fails at runtime; InvalidCastException
```

Comment: I think `Cast` would make logically more sense than `OfType` here. You don't want to filter the collection (which is what `OfType` does).

Comment: If the nongeneric works, doesn't it need a type cast in foreach?

Comment: And by "is not supported" you mean String does not implement IEnumerable<char>. It's unfortunate that the MSDN API documentation only has "supported" flags on members rather than the ability to browse WinRT as a platform, since the headline information is just wrong.

Comment: @Jani, I updated the answer. Nicholas, agree, that would be much less confusing.

Comment: Using `Cast` is not as elegant as I had hoped, but presently that seems to be the answer. Accepted.